# Why importing custom https github link with npm does not have build/dist files generated?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm curious to know why when I do a `yarn add package_name`, I correctly have it in my `node_modules` with `src/` and `build/` or `dist/` repositories, and when I fork this same repo, an do a `yarn add https://mygithuburlforthefork` I only have the `src/` files, and it results in an error.

Does npm run the build when maintainer submits the package or a new version of it?

How to handle custom forks? Currently the only workaround I found is to build and version it on my fork to be available once imported by yarn in my `node_modules` but this is absolutely ugly!

Thanks for your help!